# A function waits for another function in Java

Tags: java

I don't know if this situation is possible or not, and I don't know what should I do to achieve my needs. I have a class called A. In class A I have 02 methods (m1 and m2) and 01 thread. The thread will be responsible for listening to a socket connection for any incoming message. If a message arrives, the thread will call m1 method to process the message. The thread is started when the class is instanced.

Then I have method m2, which is responsible for sending message to the socket (the same socket that the thread is listening to). Every time the method m2 sends a message to the socket, there will be a response message from the socket. I didn't implement the code as listening to the socket right after a message is sent because the socket may sometime also send random messages.

My question is, is there any possible way, when my method m2 sends a message, it will wait until method m1 ( invoked by the thread ) finished before exiting?

Thank you very much.

Comment: http://derloki.eu/2014/12/asynchronous-methods-using-java-1-8-lambdas/ I've written a tutorial on using Java 1.8s new functionality to get async/callback methods. This may help you

Comment: Conditional Variables are used to handle wait / notify operations when mutex locks are used in critical sections.  Technically every object in Java can be used as such, but personally I like to create explicit ones using classes that implement the [`Condition`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html) interface.  This might just be because of my background where I originally learned how to do this with the pthreads library in C/C++.

Comment: Why do you want it to wait? What problem are you trying to prevent?

Comment: This sounds like the typical producer-consumer situation though, with thread 1 handling the recv (producing), and thread 2 processing (consume).  You might be better off passing these messages into a queue when thread 1 recv's and have a mutex around that queue (or use a BlockingQueue) with a condition that thread 2 only needs to wait when the queue is empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the wait/notify methods for this. You'll need some mutual object as the lock. Check out https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html for more info on that.

Comment: Surprisingly for locks you can also use [`Lock`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html) :P

Answer (score 0):

This is the typical producer consumer situation.  Thread one handling the receiving of data (produce) and thread two handles the processing of that data (consume).  I'm not sure how you're passing data between your threads, but it should be done with some sort of synchronized construct.  Here's an example on how to do this with a BlockingQueue that avoids any reason to implement locks or conditional variables directly

```
//Shared Queue
BlockingQueue<Data> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Data>();
```

Thread one (receiving)

```
//get Data object d here 
queue.put(d);
```

Assuming that you did not specify a capcity for the queue, this will not block (unless your queue is `queue.size() == Integer.MAX_VALUE`)

Thread 2 (process)

```
Data d = queue.take(); //this will block indefinitely until there is data available
//process data here
```

Since the [`BlockingQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) has locks and condition variables built into it you don't need to handle this on your own manually.  The blocking is essentially the same thing as calling `await()` (similar to `object.wait()`) and when there is data available a `signal()` (similar to `object.notify()`) is called.   This would be simplest way to accomplish what you're requesting without handling the synchronization yourself.  It also allows you to set timeouts in case you don't want to block forever.